# Why are $j=0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},\ldots$ representations of $SU(2)$ algebra irreducible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory

In quantum mechanics, we construct all the representations of the $SU(2)$ algebra $$[J_j,J_k]=i\varepsilon_{jk\ell}J_\ell$$ in the $|j,m\rangle$ basis. The allowed values of $j$ turn out to be $$j=0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},\ldots$$ which are all said to be irreducible.

Is there a theorem that we can invoke to conclude that these representations are all irreducible?

Comment: If there's an invariant subspace, it has to contain one of $|j,m\rangle$ states, because $J_3$ will have at least one eigenstate in this subspace. But if it contains one, being invariant it has to contain all of them.

Comment: Hint: Use ladder operators $J_{\pm}$ to move around in the representation.

Comment: Yes, these are well known to be the irreps of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ (= complexification of $\mathfrak{su}_2$), with highest weights $2j+1$

Comment: P. Woit's [book](https://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/QM/qmbook.pdf) explains all this from scratch.